# Encoding error while writing to a file using WriteStream in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm simply reading a text file and writing that back to another file in Node.js. I have also defined the encoding type('utf8) but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    var http = require('http')
    var fs = require('fs')

    var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/readme.txt','utf8')
    var myWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname, '/writtenText.txt','utf8')

    /* The event name is called data */
    myReadStream.on('data', function(chunk){
        myWriteStream.write(chunk)
    })
```

and the error i'm facing is:

```
    internal/fs.js:21
    throw new Error(`Unknown encoding: ${encoding}`);
    ^

Error: Unknown encoding: /writtenText.txt
    at assertEncoding (internal/fs.js:21:11)
    at getOptions (fs.js:80:5)
    at new WriteStream (fs.js:2057:24)
    at Object.fs.createWriteStream (fs.js:2048:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\meThoz\Desktop\NodeFundamentals\Streams & Buffers\Writable Stream\App.js:5:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

Could someone help me with this a little bit? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the functions like `fs.createReadStream(path, {encoding: 'utf8'})`, cf the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using Pipes :)

```
var http = require('http')
var fs = require('fs')

var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/readme.txt',{encoding: 'utf8'})
var myWriteStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/writtenText.txt',{encoding: 'utf8'})

myReadStream.pipe(myWriteStream)
```

Comment: The actual issue was that you used a comma instead of a `+` in the creation of `myWriteStream`.